# Function returning the correct date

Tags: python, function, date, dictionary

I am struggling with one task at the beginning of my journey,
I need to create a function which return a date in a correct format,
    for example: format_date(30,1,2019) = 30 january 2019 
I've done all the statements, i have a dictionary inside the function, but i cannot to join the argument responsible for months 'm' with the dictionary:

```
def format_date(d, m, y):

    m_dict = {
        1: "january",
        2: "february",
        3: "march",
        4: "april",
        5: "may",
        6: "june",
        7: "july",
        8: "august",
        9: "september",
        10: "october",
        11: "november",
        12: "december",
    }



    if m == 4 or m == 6 or m == 9 or m == 1:
        if d > 0 and d < 31:
            return d, m, y
        else:
            return None

    if m == 1 or m == 3 or m == 5 or m == 7 or m == 8 or m == 10 or m == 12:
        if d > 0 and d < 32:
            return d, m, y
        else:
            return None

    if m > 0 and m < 13:
        return d, m, y
    else:
        return None



d = format_date(30, 1, 2010)
print(d)
```

Comment: You'll want to return `m_dict[m]` instead of just `m`…!?

Comment: ```m_dict[m]``` would be how you can get month name - you can put it that way in your ```return``` statement

Comment: you can write it shorter  `if m in (4, 6, 9, 1):` and  `if 0 < m < 13:`

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_date(d, m, y):
    m_dict = {
        1: "styczen",
        2: "luty",
        3: "marzec",
        4: "kwiecien",
        5: "maj",
        6: "czerwiec",
        7: "lipiec",
        8: "sierpien",
        9: "wrzesien",
        10: "pazdziernik",
        11: "listopad",
        12: "grudzien",
    }

if m == 4 or m == 6 or m == 9 or m == 1:
    if d > 0 and d < 31:
        return d, m_dict[m], y
    else:
        return None

if m == 1 or m == 3 or m == 5 or m == 7 or m == 8 or m == 10 or m == 12:
    if d > 0 and d < 32:
        return d, m_dict[m], y
    else:
        return None

if m > 0 and m < 13:
        return d, m_dict[m], y
else:
        return None


d = format_date(30, 1, 2010)
print(d)
```

Works, thanks guys :)